# Does running an Ubuntu docker image on an Ubuntu host run faster than running the same Docker image on any other OS?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, containers, virtualization

I was told that running the same Docker image OS as the local host OS would avoid a virtualization layer of some kind, but I can’t find documentation supporting this. For example, does Ubuntu 18.04 image run faster on Docker installed on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

No, a Linux container will run equally fast on any Linux distribution. The container is only dependent on the Kernel, which is the same in all Linux distributions.

However if you run a Linux container on Windows there is no native Linux Kernel available on the system. Docker for Windows solves that by running a virtual machine of a slimmed down Linux distribution to create an environment in which the container can run. There is a small overhead in doing this so it is true that running a Linux container on Windows is slower due to virtualization. The same goes for running Linux containers on iOS.